# Having trouble setting up XDebug on Atom with php-debug and Local by Flywheel

Tags: php, wordpress, xdebug

Trying to set up XDebug on my local WordPress project using Atom, but running into issues. I can set breakpoints in my code but when I load a page it seems to skip right over the breakpoint.

My setup:

`php.ini`:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = /opt/php/5.6.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.remote_port="4022"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.95.100
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.idekey=xdebug-atom
```

---

`config.cson`:

```
"*":
  editor: {}
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "my-user-id-number"
  "php-debug":
    PathMaps: [
      "/remote/path;/local/path"
      "/app/public;/Users/my.user/Documents/Work Stuff/Company/Project Name/app/public"
    ]
    ServerAddress: "192.168.95.100"
    ServerPort: 4022
    currentPanelMode: "bottom"
```

---

result of `ping mysite.dev`

```
64 bytes from 192.168.95.100: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.476 ms
```

---

Local by Flywheel setup:
[image]

---

Atom screenshot w/ breakpoint:
[image]

When I load the page, the breakpoint doesn't seem to work (the content generated by `get_header()` is still loaded) and nothing changes in my debug section in Atom. I've already confirmed I'm loading up the right page/template file in my browser.

Something misconfigured, or am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Try checking xdebug documentation first (e.g. https://xdebug.org/docs/remote to have good understanding of how it works) -- quite likely you have misunderstood some things. **1)** I'm confused with port `4022` being used everywhere. If it's meant for xdebug (php.ini) then why it's also used in screenshot for "Local by Flywheel setup" where Database tab is shown? That port should be used for xdebug puposes ONLY.

Comment: **2)** You are using local Flyweel. From what I understand it uses Docker containers .. which means IP for WordPress site is not the same as IP for your Atom editor (debug client) .. therefore `192.168.95.100` *might be* wrong here. Check documentation -- the IP should be the one where you editor is running .. as it's xdebug that connects to client and not other way around.